# iscroll 5 multiple clicks

Tags: android, cordova, click, iscroll

Is there a way to solve the Iscroll 5 issue where the android browser seems to register multiple click. I have looked around but there is no solid solutions. If you click on a select box for example it opens the select box many times. I am having this issue on lollipop and kitkat and am using iscroll 5(latest). Downgrading Iscroll does not work either. I have click set to true.

Here is a sample of my code below:

```
    var myScroll;

    function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#mydiv2', { 
                mouseWheel: true,
                checkDOMChanges: false,
                topOnDOMChanges: false,
                scrollX: false, 
                scrollY: true,
                click:true,
                scrollbars: false,
                useTransform: true,
                useTransition: false,
                probeType:3,    
                tap: true
                      });

    var myScroll2 = new IScroll('#mywrapper', { 
                mouseWheel: true,
                checkDOMChanges: false,
                topOnDOMChanges: false,
                scrollX: false, 
                scrollY: true,
                click:true,
                scrollbars: false,
                useTransform: true,
                useTransition: false,
                probeType:3,
                tap: true
                      });

    }


    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { 
    console.log('touch');e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem and this works for me

**The solution, just add this code in the top of the iscroll.js**

```
var last_click_time = new Date().getTime();
$("a").live("click", function(ev) {
     var click_time = ev["timeStamp"];
     if (click_time && (click_time - last_click_time) < 1000) {
          ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
          return false;
     }    
     last_click_x = click_x;
     last_click_y = click_y;
     last_click_time = click_time;
});
```

Source: https://www.scirra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=74123&start=0

Comment: Thanks for this. I just ended up removing iscroll completely an used basic css overflow. Its just as fast and far more simpler. Also project is lighter now